# Detecting *working* Vulkan implementation on Android?

Tags: android, vulkan, standards-compliance

In theory, on Android one can query `FEATURE_VULKAN_HARDWARE_VERSION` at runtime to determine whether a device has a working Vulkan implementation, and based on the result either enable a (faster) Vulkan code path or fall back to OpenGL ES 3.x. In practice, however, there is quite a long list of devices that have Vulkan drivers present, but whose driver quality lies somewhere between buggy and broken - meaning that on those devices using Vulkan either produces visual artifacts or outright crashes.

So what's the best practice for reliably running an app with Vulkan on as many devices as possible (i.e. falling back to OpenGL ES for as few devices as possible) on Android while leaving the app unusable due to Vulkan driver bugs on as few devices as possible?

My solution would be to

- *enable* Vulkan for devices running Android 10 and above (where Vulkan drivers should be mature enough), **minus** those on a manually maintained blacklist
- *disable* Vulkan on devices running Android 9 and below, **unless** they are on a manually maintained whitelist

But I'm wondering whether there are better approaches, or whether there is an existing library or online device database about *practical* Vulkan usability?

Comment: As well as blacklists/whitelists we automatically fallback to OpenGLES if there's been a few failed boots. That way, users with Vulkan problems at least get to run eventually, the software has an opportunity to download the latest blacklist/whitelists, and the user could manually disable Vulkan.

Comment: @Columbo yes, using failed application startups as an indicator of a non-working Vulkan driver is one more good safety measure. It won't protect against those driver bugs that simply lead to visual garbage, though. And you'd need to set that failed startup limit pretty low (probably to one), since users tend to give up on an application after very few failed startups and just uninstall it (plus, leaving a bad review).

Comment: We consider a failed boot as one where the user doesn't press the button to proceed past the landing screen, hopefully effective for catching visual garbage/black screen because it's hard to press a button you can't see. This approach catches more issues but we don't set our limit as low as you suggest because there'd be too many false-positives from users just multitasking away before doing anything. Also the graphical complexity of the frontend is very low compared to later on, so there's still plenty of major graphical issues we don't catch this way. It's all a bit of a bodge.